# Which function grows faster : n or $(\log n)^c$ where $c$ is a constant

Tags: limits, logarithms

First function is : $n$

Second is : $(\log n)^c$

so is the second function smaller than the first one for any constant $c$? if not then for which constant $c$ it's bigger and for which its smaller?

$c > 0$

$n > 0$

A video i was watching said $n$ is bigger than $(\log n)^{100}$ and this is really confusing me..

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{log(x)^c}{x}=0$. Use L'hopital. This is the nalogous of the fact $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{c^x}{e^x}=0$.

Comment: OK, $n>\log n$ is true for $n> 1.3\times 10^{281}$.It is true also for $0.371522<n<2.74602$

Comment: The derivative of $y=n$ is 1, but the derivative of $y=log^c n$ is $\frac{c}{n}$. So for sufficiently large $n$, the first function will always overtake the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every $x>0$ is equal to $e^t$, for some real number $t$. So$$x>(\log x)^{100}\iff e^t>(\log(e^t))^{100}=t^{100}$$and, yes, if $t$ is large enough ($\iff x$ is large enough), then $e^t>t^{100}$. The exponential function grows faster than any polynomial function.

Comment: Wow i didn't know that Every $x>0$ is equal to $e^t$, for some real number $t$ ! do you have any link to proof of this statement ?

Comment: Also that's true for any c > 1 then right ?

Comment: @EdaiBossinShid If $x\geqslant1$, there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $e^n\geqslant x\geqslant e^0$. Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, there is some $t\in[0,n]$ such that $e^t=x$. And if $0<x\leqslant1$, take $t\in[0,+\infty)$ such that $e^t=\frac1x$ and then $e^{-t}=\frac1{1/x}=x$. And, yes, what I did holds for any $c>1$.